ExchangeService impossible to AutodiscoverUrl in windows service
This is my problem,

I use EWS and I manage to connect very well when the UseDefaultCredentials = true when I am on my winforms, but as soon as I am in my windows application the AutodiscoverUrl does not work and I have "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located" as an error,
or I try to skip all the code when my URL is filled, but I get this error " The request failed. Le serveur distant a retourné une erreur : (401) Non autorisé "
Do you have any idea why it works in one case and not the other and how to fix it?

Do you have proxy server ? generally for NTLM/Kerberos you want to bypass the proxy for onPrem exchange because it will break the auth. I would check if you winforms is using a different internet config you can enable tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications to see what is happening at the lower request level

Of course - when running as an interactive app, it can use cached credentials. When running as a service, even if the local user account is the same, security context is, so there are no cached credentials. The OAuth flow for the service apps is different - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/getting-started/initializing-client-applications

I made a modification following your advice and it works perfectly, but my response does not want to put it in place because I site is "too boring to set up", so I went with something like that

but I have an error which is: "
Inner Exception 1:
MsalServiceException: AADSTS9001023: The grant type is not supported over the /common or /consumers endpoints. Please use the /organizations or tenant-specific endpoint.
"

This is not an answer, so you should have posted it as a comment. Moreover, please don't post the code as an image. Put it as a text. Otherwise, the others cannot test it nor search for it.

my answer solves the problem if I had put it in a comment, people having the same problem as me might not have seen the solution

 var clientsAccessTokenType = new Dictionary<string, ClientAccessTokenType>
        {
            { ExchangeService.GetAppManifests().FirstOrDefault().DocumentElement.FirstChild.InnerText, ClientAccessTokenType.ExtensionCallback }
        };

        AccessToken.Token = ExchangeService.GetClientAccessToken(clientsAccessTokenType).FirstOrDefault().TokenValue;
        AccessToken.Utilisateur = _account;

With this modification that I made just after the if in the gettoken I was able to obtain a token and make the application connect with it like this
    exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(_config.CleSecret);
exchangeService.Url = new Uri(_config.Hostname);

thanks to Dmitry Streblechenko who gave me the idea
